# SQL Server Agent gives- Remote procedure call failed (0x800706be)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Does Anyone knows the solution to this problem m not being able to run the  SQL Server Services.

[image]

Comment: I advise you to try what is written in this article

http://www.tegenaria.com/insane/2008/12/12/getting-sql-server-express-2008-to-work-the-way-you-probably-want-it-to/

However, it involves a new sql server installation.

Comment: Try the solutions on these two posts: [http://thesqldude.com/2012/12/05/sql-server-2012-configuration-manager-wmi-error-remote-procedure-call-failed-0x800706be/](http://thesqldude.com/2012/12/05/sql-server-2012-configuration-manager-wmi-error-remote-procedure-call-failed-0x800706be/) [http://thuruinhttp.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/sql-configuration-manager-wmi-errorremote-procedure-call-failed-0x800706be/](http://thuruinhttp.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/sql-configuration-manager-wmi-errorremote-procedure-call-failed-0x800706be/) I'm in the process of checking it now, so I can't personally attest to t

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With all due respect, "Right click on configuration manager and run as administrator" is a bogus answer.  I also have this problem with the following series of events: I download the Windows Azure SDK from here:  http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/downloads/, which installs SQL 2012 express; immediate I try to run SQL Server Configuration Manager, and the installation of SQL 2012 has broken it such that I get the "remote procedure call failed".  That is true even if I "run as administrator".  Microsoft says they can't reproduce this, but I've contacted them again because I've now reproduced this twice.  And, if there's any doubt:  un-installing SQL 2012 causes the problem to go away, and the configuration manager works again.  I blogged about it here:  http://dbarrowstechblog.blogspot.com/2012/09/the-remote-procedure-call-failed.html ; haven't solved it yet.

Comment: @codingbiz , I never did solve it, and I'm in a different job now so I don't have that machine anymore.  The gist of what MS told me was, "there's a (SQL 2008 R2) service pack that should fix that", but I was developing every day on that machine and maybe it was undue caution on my part, but I didn't want to break my SQL configuration.  I uninstalled SQL 2012, I think, to get my SQL 2008 config manager to start working again.  But never (on that machine) managed to solve the issue of the Azure SDK breaking the config manager.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I also saw that on microsoft site. Should be as simple as that. I think SQL 2012 upgraded some stuff on the system. I've also not tried it cos I could do without it to solve my problem.

Comment: I also installed SQL Server 2014 when I already had SQL Server 2008 R2 but I'm not sure my configuration manager for SQL Server 2008 R2 was working correctly before this installation or not. But it seems whenever you install a new edition the configuration manager of older version starts facing issues. The configuration manager for SQL Server 2014 is working fine and is able to show all instances on my computer.

Answer (score 14):

Solution: Install  [SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30437), restart, open SQL Server Configuration Manager and ALL is good.

Source: [Frozen bytes](https://web.archive.org/web/20140209042004/http://www.i-m-code.com/blog/blog/2013/07/19/sql-server-2008-r2-configuration-manager-wmi-error-saga/)

Comment: I had the same problem described in the question, so I did a check for Windows Updates. It offered 'Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 3', which fixed the issue after installing it.

Comment: Yep! This worked for me. My SQL Server version before SP2 upgrade was `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) Apr 2 2010 15:48:46 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)`. After upgrading it to SP2 it got fixed.

Answer (score 13):

No need to re-install or update your SQL Server 2008 R2 instance. I got the same error and it get resolved by simply starting the MSSQLSERVER standard service.

**How to start this service:**

Open Administrative Tasks > Services > Select Standard services tab > start SQL Server Agent(MSSQLSERVER) service and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs only after I have installed the Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 setup in my work machine.

Since it is being a WMI error, I recompiled the MOF file –> mofcomp.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"

I also un-registered and re-registered the sql provider DLL –> regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmprovider.dll" but issue not resolved.

**Solution:**

I have applied SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 on my SQL 2008 R2 instance and that fixed the issue with Sql Server Configuration Manager. You can download setup from here... http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30437 .

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Stop this.

Is this a new Installation?

1. Open SSMS in Integrated security Mode
2. Right click on server name in Object explorer tree at the left
3. Select properties -> Then choose the "Security" page at left
4. Under Server Authentication, select "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode"
5. Click OK
6. Exit SSMS completely
7. Open "SQL Server Configuration Manager" (in Configuration menu under the "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2" menu item from start menu
8. Select you instance on SQLExpress and restart the instance of the server (but this is ok for non express too)
9. Exit SSCM - and to verify open SSMS again, but with "SQL Server Authentication" selected in the Authentication type dropdown - put in your SQL user ID and password.

Answer (score 0):

installing the SP3 on SQL server 2008 worked for me..so give it try 
Thanks!! dont forget to vote up if this helps you