# Remote Procedure call failed with sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working with SQL Server 2008 R2. I am unable to connect to my database remotely. I got the following error.

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection 
>   to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance 
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)*

I have checked the SQL Server properties and I enable the **Allow remote connections**.

I have checked the Service manager and **SQL Server service** are running.

I have checked the configuration manager, I can't see any services under SQL Server Services
and it shows **Remote Procedure call failed**

[image]

So please guide me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589964/sql-server-agent-gives-remote-procedure-call-failed-0x800706be

Answer (score 34):

Open Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services > Select Standard services tab (under the bottom) > Find start SQL Server Agent

Right Click and select properties,

Startup Type : Automatic,

Apply, Ok.

Done.

Comment: Thanks it works for me :) .. Thanking out of the box is really good ;)

Comment: As an additional info to @sunnyuff's post: sometimes you have to run 'Services' as an Administrator - in other case you are not be able to run SQLEXPRESS service.

Comment: Worked for me. You saved my day. Tks

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot @sunnyuff  I had automatic alreay but didnt work some how even though i have started as administrator but then after force it to start

Answer (score 31):

I just had the same issue and was able to solve it by installing [Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26727).

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked for me (solution from sunnyuff did not)

Answer (score 11):

This error occurs only after I have installed the Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 setup in my work machine.

Since it is being a WMI error, I recompiled the MOF file –> mofcomp.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"

I also un-registered and re-registered the sql provider DLL –> regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmprovider.dll" but issue not resolved.

**Solution:**

I have applied SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 on my SQL 2008 R2 instance and that fixed the issue with Sql Server Configuration Manager. You can download setup from here... http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30437 .

Comment: This worked for me. My SQL Server version before SP2 upgrade was `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) Apr 2 2010 15:48:46 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)`. After upgrading it to SP2 it got fixed.

Comment: After installing SP2 you need to restart your machine. Worked for me

Answer (score 11):

After trying everything between Stackoverflow and Google, I finally found a solution : http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbadmin/remote-procedure-call-failed/

**TL;DR :**

If you are (or were) running multiple versions of SQL Server on your machine, that Configuration Manager shortcut on your start menu might be pointing to an older version, which it shouldn't be. It was pointing to an old Sql Server 2008 instance in my case.

The solution was to :

1. Go to either C:\Windows\SysWOW64 or C:\Windows\System32, depending on your system.
2. Look for an executable called SQLServerManagerXX.msc, and run the latest version if you have multiple ones. In my case, I had both SQLServerManager11.msc and SQLServerManager10.msc, where the 10th gave the error, and the 11th worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, but make sure you made all the checks in this quide: [How to enable remote connections in SQL Server 2008?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) It should work fine if all steps are made.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your SQL Server to SP3

You can install it from:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27594

Comment: How does this upgrade go to dealing with the problem outlined in the question? Without more specific information, this answer is not helpful.

Comment: Especially since the link is to a 2008 SP, not 2008 R2. (Much newer) SP3 for that: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44271

Answer (score 0):

> This error appears to happen when .mof files (Managed Object Format (MOF)) don’t get installed and registered correctly during set-up. To resolve this issue, I executed the following mofcomp command in command prompt to re-register the *.mof files:
>
> mofcomp.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"

[This one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/569ee2d4-0805-40e2-a4f0-10f7d573fd75/) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

start SQL Server Agent from the command prompt using:

```
SQLAGENT90 -C -V>C:\SQLAGENT.OUT
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install SQL Server 2008 SP3.

[SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27594)

[SQL Server 2012 Configuration Manager WMI Error – Remote Procedure call failed [0x800706be]](http://thesqldude.com/2012/12/05/sql-server-2012-configuration-manager-wmi-error-remote-procedure-call-failed-0x800706be/)

Answer (score 0):

I got the samilar issue, while both SQLServer and SQLServerAgent services are running.  The error is fixed by a restart of services.

```
Server Manager > Service > 
    SQL Server > Stop
    SQL Server > Start
    SQL Server Agent > Start
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Control Panel
Administrative Tools
Services
Select Extended services tab

Find SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER)  &  SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS)
Stop these services and Start again (from the start & stop button displayed above)

Done.