# There was an unknown error applying the filestream settings. check the parameters are valid

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlfilestream

I am getting the following error while trying to configure FileStream in SQL server 2012.

**There was an unknown error applying the filestream settings. check the parameters are valid. (0x80041008)**

I am configuring it using SQL server configuration manager.

Where as I am able to setup it for SQL server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem just yesterday.

In my case it was because I had a 64-bit Windows and a 32-Bit SQL Server.

You do not see the exact error, but if you try to do it with T-SQL, then the proper error comes up in SQL, telling you something about "WOW64" not supporting filestream.

I just uninstalled and installed the right bit version of SQL, and all worked 100% again.

Comment: Is there any other possibility for this error? I've got 64 bit windows 7 and my SQL Server 2008 R2 is also 64 bit which is evident from @@version - `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)`

Comment: To enable the feature first you have to enable the feature from SQL Server configuration manager UI. I've not seen any T-SQL anywhere to enable the feature for the SQL Server installation. You can only configure the `File Stream access level` using `EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 2`. Can you please share the T-SQL script you are talking about which gives "WOW64" specific error.

Comment: This was LONG ago, I cannot remember this anymore... however, I'm sure the script you posted above was the one producing the "WOW64" error. You are also using SQL 2008, maybe that produces another error from SQL 2012. I cannot think of any other cause for this error, sorry!

Comment: I was finally able to fix the issue by installing SP2 patch of SQL Server 2008 R2. I've also added my experience as an answer in case it helps someone. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem I was running the SQL Server **2014** configuration manager. While this usually shouldn't cause problems, in my case it did. Configuring FILESTREAM using the SQL Server *2012* configuration manager worked.

If it still doesn't work, make sure you're up-to-date. SQL Server 2012 has received quite a lot of patches (SP2, SP3, and some updates).

Comment: same issue with 2017 config mgr trying to config 2016 SQL

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

*I simply installed Service pack 2 (SP2) patch of SQL Server 2008 R2 and everything started working for me.*

Read on if you want to know more. Configuration wise my box was all correct and the file stream feature should have been working on my default instance of SQL Server 2008 R2. Here are my box details:

```
Operating System: Windows 7 Ultitmate SP1 (64 Bit)
SQL Server Version: SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1
```

On SQL Server if I run this query `select @@version` it was returning following details:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) Apr 2 2010 15:48:46 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Whenever I opened SQL Server 2008 Configuration manager I will face [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589964/sql-server-agent-gives-remote-procedure-call-failed-0x800706be) issue. Luckily I also had SQL Server 2014 installed on my machine. So I tried enabling File Stream feature from configuration manager GUI of SQL Server 2014 but it started giving error mentioned in current post.

I simply installed Service pack 2 (SP2) patch of SQL Server 2008 R2 and everything started working for me. SQL Server Configuration manager for 2008 R2 also works fine and I'm able to enable File Stream feature also without any trouble. SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 can be downloaded from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30437).

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen on two different fresh installations of SQL 2016 standard edition.  We ended up going to MS support, and they advised us to perform a repair on the instance (under the SQL Server installation center), which we did, and the problem was solved.  We were able to enable Filestream on the instance with no error.  It seems ridiculous to have to "repair" a fresh install, but I've had it fix the Filestream issue twice now.